# jQuery AJAX submit Help

Tags: jquery

I have a form that lets a user perform a search for a stock symbol. The data is transmitted to another URL via PHP cURL. This is fine, we do this several other places on the site. I need to be able to trim the returned data (it returns a whole page) and only display the data between the
{STARTKINETICK}
{ENDKINETICK}
 parts.

I need to have it displayed in a div#results. Please help! this should be so simple!

```
$(document).click(function() { 
$("#SymbolSearchForm").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
     url: "PHP/Kinetick_Symbol_Search.php",
     type: "post",
     dataType: "HTML",
      success: function(html){
        html = $.trim(html);
        html = html.match(/\{STARTKINETICK\}(.*)\{ENDKINETICK\}/)[1];
        var end = "{ENDKINETICK}";
        $("#return").append(html.substring(html.indexOf("{STARTKINETICK}"), html.indexOf(end) + end.length));
    }

    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `html.indexOf("{STARTKINETICK}")` and `html.indexOf("{ENDKINETICK}")` to get the starting and ending points and then use `html.substring`.  Don't forget to add the length of "{STARTKINETICK}" to the start point.

*EDIT*

```
var start = "{STARTKINETICK}";
html = html.substring(html.indexOf(start) + start.length, html.indexOf("{ENDKINETICK}");
```

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with edited code above? it doesn't seem to be binding to my form, it has no ajax functionality

Comment: I've edited my answer.  I originally misread the question and thought you wanted the start and end labels too, not just the data inbetween.  You should either use my solution or Topera's, but not both.  If the substring issue is resolved, you'll probably get the most help by accepting an answer here and creating a new question with your AJAX/append issue.  Is your issue that it doesn't return the html, or that it doesn't append to the div?

Comment: If you doing a submit, but don't want to go to the submit action, you need to `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Regex that you need:

```
"foo{STARTKINETICK}myText{ENDKINETICK}bar".match(/\{STARTKINETICK\}(.*)\{ENDKINETICK\}/)[1]; // returns myText
```

Whole code:

```
success: function(html){
    html = $.trim(html);
    html = html.match(/\{STARTKINETICK\}(.*)\{ENDKINETICK\}/)[1];
    $("#return").append(html);
}
```

Comment: could you take a look at my code, its not staying on the page, rather going to the action

Comment: I don't get it...I give you the answer, you put it in your code and I don't give any rep??

Comment: it didn't work, i apologize for not getting you "points" or whatever, if you like Ill make you a badge

Comment: @dirty "Make you a badge" - Ok, I'll never waste my time again trying to help disrespectfull people. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

A bit off topic, but do you know that jQuery has a nice method - [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that loads html asynchronously. Moreover, you can pass element selector that should be extracted from the result. If you can control the server side, you can wrap {STARTKINETICK} and {ENDKINETICK} in `<div id="to_be_extracted"></div>` and call

`$('#return').load('PHP/Kinetick_Symbol_Search.php #to_be_extracted');`

I use this technique here and there and find it very useful.

Comment: that's pretty slick. so you can submit a form through the PHP/cURL without any of the ajax submit stuff? the only issue is that the returned data doesn't have an ID.

Comment: actually - it's about AJAX, just another 'smart' method.